# Haskell non exhaustive pattern - error

Tags: haskell, boolean

I've got this code

```
andAll :: [Bool] -> Bool
andAll (x:xs) = x && andAll xs
```

and when I run it, it gives me `'*** Exception: worksheet5.hs:80:1-30: Non-exhaustive patterns in function andAll'`  after some research it seems I need to add a case for an empty list. I'm not quite sure how to specify this, i tried `andAll [] = []` but this still gave an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern `(x:xs)` will only match a sequence with at least one element. You need to add a pattern to match the empty sequence.

```
andAll :: [Bool] -> Bool
andAll (x:xs) = x && andAll xs
andAll [] = True
```

Comment: Ahh! just realised how silly i've been `[]` clearly isnt a 'Bool' output. Thanks! :)

Comment: Note that the error on `[]` not being `Bool` was not the same error as the one you posted. Be sure to post questions as clearly as possible, and include the actual error messages.